# How to pass Url as value in Hyperlink field Type in List Instance?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-foundation

I have try to add Url as value in List Instance.

```
  <ListInstance Title="Lists Link"
            TemplateType="1005"
            Description="All Lists Link Url in This Custom List"
            OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
            Id="1258"
            Url="Lists/ListsLink">
<Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field Name="Title">News</Field>
      <Field Name="ListUrl">/Lists/News/AllItems.aspx</Field>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Field Name="Title">Tips Of The Week</Field>
      <Field Name="ListUrl">/Lists/TipsOfTheWeek/AllItems.aspx</Field>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>
```

its add in field but when m creating site collection url was contain root web url..

like as suppose my site collection is http://gtsp10:1000/sites/rbk/Lists/TipsOfTheWeek/AllItems.aspx  but redirect to http://gtsp10:1000/Lists/TipsOfTheWeek/AllItems.aspx..

Is this right way to going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe a special character like $site or something ?  In any case you could always revert to using a feature activation event receiver and code the creation of the data in the list.

Ian.

Comment: i was tried to using   $Resources:cmscore,ListName_UrlName;/AllItems.aspx but got the error..i agree ur answer maybe use feature receiver to solve this issues.

Answer (score -1):

Use `~site/...` or `~sitecollection/...`